# Phone call fails to Nexmo number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, vonage

When trying to call my Nexmo number, it never goes through (call fails). Below is all the code I have written. Do I have to create a view to be returned? Is this returning an NCCO correctly? I'd appreciate some help with figuring out what's wrong. I've had some fantastic help from staff with regards to websockets, but I don't seem to be able to answer the call in the first place...

```
public class NexmoController : Controller
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public NexmoController()
    {
        Client = new Client(creds: new Nexmo.Api.Request.Credentials
        {
            ApiKey = "abcdefg1234567",
            ApiSecret = "abcde12345",
            ApplicationId = "5f01ae77-26dc-4814-9a7a-db447bb6503e",
            ApplicationKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...abc123...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
        });
    }

    // GET: Nexmo
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var NEXMO_CALL_UUID = Session["UUID"].ToString();
        var TEXT = "This is a text to speech sample";

        var result = Client.Call.BeginTalk(NEXMO_CALL_UUID, new Nexmo.Api.Voice.Call.TalkCommand
        {
            text = TEXT,
            voice_name = "Kimberly"
        });

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I've encountered an error with bad credentials when the ApplicationKey is a string instead of a path to the private key file.